# Office 2007 Calendar Overlays - Combine meetings that everybody shares

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, calendar

I want to display approximately 10 people's calendar in Outlook 2007 using overlays.  The problem is that they all share the same meeting a couple of times a week.  Thus, I see that show up 10 times on a single day, which compresses what is actually displayed.  Since they are all at the same meeting(s), it would be nice to have them just display once.

Is this built into Office 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the Calendar view, use the new meeting request and if you are all on the same exchange server, you should use the scheduling view of the new meeting request to find the best time to meet.

Hope this helps.